# Automatically resizing iframe height

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, polyfills

I'm rendering external content in an iframe and trying to automatically resize the iframe to fit the content height. Easiest solution I found so far is to simply set the iframe height to the document's scroll height. This works great, however, the content includes some expandable elements that trigger a resize. I'd like to reliably detect these changes **without** polling. The ResizeObserver looks promising but obviously still a draft. The MutationObserver could work for this too, except that it fires before layout occurs and doesn't handle CSS transitions.
Ideas? A polyfill for the ResizeObserver might actually work, but just seeing if there are other solutions out there.

Comment: ResizeObserver includes iframe resize as one of its examples: https://cdn.rawgit.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/351d5d40/examples/iframe_demo.html